# virtual wx.ListCtrl raises wxAssertionError on SetItemCount

Tags: python, wxpython, virtual, listctrl

I want to create a custom ListCtrl "MyListCtrlCrafting" which pulls the data from a different class called "DBInterface" (actually it is not a real database, but a sophisticated python dictionary). There are tutorials on how to do that, I followed "Python in Action". The main points are: inherit from ListCtrl an set the style parameter to wx.LC_REPORT | wx.LC_SINGLE_SEL | wx.LC_VIRTUAL, call SetItemCount() during **init**() and override some methods.

To test how that works I made a small App which consists only of one (main-)frame, the virtual ListCtrl and a rudimentary version of DBInterface. Everything works out fine in this setting. But when I connect the classes of the real App, I get a Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DesktopCrafter.py", line 198, in <module>
    controller = AppCtrl()
  File "DesktopCrafter.py", line 186, in __init__
    self.frame = GUI.MainWindow(back_end=self.back_end, crafting_controller=self.crafting_controller, parent=None, title='Desktop Crafter')
...
    self.view = MyListCtrlCrafting(name='crafting-hand', back_end=self.db, crafting_controller=self.cc, parent=self, id=wx.ID_ANY)
  File "d:\workspace-fun\DesktopCrafter\dc\util\DCUI.py", line 107, in __init__
    self.bindData()
  File "d:\workspace-fun\DesktopCrafter\dc\util\DCUI.py", line 121, in bindData
    self.SetItemCount(count)
wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "m_count == ListView_GetItemCount(GetHwnd())" failed at ..\..\src\msw\listctrl.cpp(3120) in wxListCtrl::SetItemCount(): m_count should match ListView_GetItemCount
```

In contrast to the simple App, the virtualListCtrl is now deeply nested. Can this error just be produced by wrong connections inside this nesting or between DBInterface and the ListCtrl? Or do I have to understand how m_count is calculated, to solve this error? If so, how can I read the _core file? I already read about ListCtrl in the core.py file, but it doesn't contain the relevant parts.

My problem with this traceback is that I don't understand why it is raised during SetItemCount(). This method should be something like a definition and since it is dealing with rows of a list, it should accept positive integers, and maybe 0, and maybe also -1 for standard. I plug in 5, so this cannot be the real problem going on here(?)

Any help or hint is much appreciated!

The complete Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DesktopCrafter.py", line 198, in <module>
    controller = AppCtrl()
  File "DesktopCrafter.py", line 186, in __init__
    self.frame = GUI.MainWindow(back_end=self.back_end, crafting_controller=self.crafting_controller, parent=None, title='Desktop Crafter')
  File "d:\workspace-fun\DesktopCrafter\dc\util\DCUI.py", line 285, in __init__
    self.InitUI()
  File "d:\workspace-fun\DesktopCrafter\dc\util\DCUI.py", line 299, in InitUI
    self.panel = MainPanel(back_end=self.db, crafting_controller=self.cc)
  File "d:\workspace-fun\DesktopCrafter\dc\util\DCUI.py", line 251, in __init__
    self.splitter = MySplitter(back_end=back_end, crafting_controller=crafting_controller)
  File "d:\workspace-fun\DesktopCrafter\dc\util\DCUI.py", line 229, in __init__
    self.l_frame = LPanel(back_end=back_end, crafting_controller=crafting_controller)
  File "d:\workspace-fun\DesktopCrafter\dc\util\DCUI.py", line 188, in __init__
    self.panel = CraftingPanel(back_end=back_end, crafting_controller=crafting_controller, *args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\workspace-fun\DesktopCrafter\dc\util\DCUI.py", line 154, in __init__
    self.view = MyListCtrlCrafting(name='crafting-hand', back_end=self.db, crafting_controller=self.cc, parent=self, id=wx.ID_ANY)
  File "d:\workspace-fun\DesktopCrafter\dc\util\DCUI.py", line 107, in __init__
    self.bindData()
  File "d:\workspace-fun\DesktopCrafter\dc\util\DCUI.py", line 121, in bindData
    self.SetItemCount(count)
wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "m_count == ListView_GetItemCount(GetHwnd())" failed at ..\..\src\msw\listctrl.cpp(3120) in wxListCtrl::SetItemCount(): m_count should match ListView_GetItemCount
```

The virtual ListCtrl (both print's give me the expected results):

```
 class MyListCtrlCrafting(wx.ListCtrl):


    def __init__(self, name, back_end, crafting_controller, *args, **kwargs):

        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, style=wx.LC_REPORT | wx.LC_SINGLE_SEL | wx.LC_VIRTUAL, *args, **kwargs)

        self.name = name
        self.db = back_end 
        self.cc = crafting_controller
        #print(self.db.retrieveValue(['player', self.name]))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_CACHE_HINT, self.DoCacheItems)

        self.bindData()

        self.InsertColumn(0, "Slot")
        self.InsertColumn(1, "Item")
        self.InsertColumn(2, "Amount")      

        print("initialized MyListCtrl")


    def bindData(self):

        data = self.db.retrieveValue(['player', self.name])
        count = len(data)
        #print(count)
        self.itemDataMap = {i: ('slot'+str(i+1), data[str(i)]['item'], data[str(i)]['amount']) for i in range(count)}
        self.SetItemCount(count)

    def DoCacheItems(self, e):

        self.db.updateCache(e.GetCacheFrom(), e.GetCacheTo())           

    def OnGetItemText(self, row_no, col_no):

        data = self.db.retrieveValue(['player', self.name, str(row_no)])    
        return data[col_no]

    def OnGetItemAttr(self, item): return None
    def OnGetItemImage(self, item): return -1

    def OnBackEndUpdated(self):

        self.bindData()
        self.RefreshItems(0, self.GetItemCount())
```

The DBInterface:

```
 class DBInterface(dict):


    def __init__(self, path, *args, **kwargs):        

        super(DBInterface, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.path = path


    def load(self):

        with open(self.path, 'r') as f:
            try:
                self.update(json.loads(f.read()))
            except Exception as e:
                print(e); print(self.path)


    def save(self):

        self.path.ensure()
        with open(self.path, 'w') as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(self))


    def retrieveValue(self, path):

        a = self
        for i in range(len(path)):
            a = a[path[i]]
        return a
```

Comment: This question can be deleted as it is not helpful for others. The problem was that I forgot to set the parent- and id-parameters of the panels, splitter, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That assert is basically a check to ensure that the operation (setting the count) was successful, by asking the native control how many items it has (which should have been set by the prior API call. It seems like something that really shouldn't be able to fail, although obviously it is. Perhaps something is resetting or changing the native control somehow? Are there any threads involved?

I don't have a solid answer for you, but as advice I would suggest taking the small sample that works and build it up step by step until it matches the window hierarchy and environment and basic features of that part of the full application where it is broken. Eventually it should start failing the same way and then you'll know what changed that triggered it and can look more closely at that.

Comment: Ok thanks for your advice. Concerning your questions: i don't know if something resets the control, threads are not involved. Could you say another word about reading the _core file? Is it forbidden to read or do I just need the right glasses?